# Access How to save text in a specific table?

Tags: ms-access, sorting, filter, save

Within my database i have 3 different tables for different members. When saving the members details i use a form to save the members all to the same table but i would like to save them to a specific table depending on their details. for example if a member has registered with their school email i would like them to be saved within the student table, if they have used a freemail email address to be saved in the freemail table etc

Would this be run as a query or sorting the one table using if statements?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not have three tables, just a field that defines the member type. You may wish to read [Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://r937.com/relational.html).

If you really insist on having three tables, even though it is likely to cause ever more tangled scenarios, you will either have to use VBA to gather the data from an unbound form and  then fill it into the appropriate table, or ask the user which table they wish to update before you start and set up the form for that table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your development environment.  You can either change the `switch` to an `If` clause at business level or you can implement it as a database procedure.  It's up to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214(v=sql.80).aspx explains how to use If clause in database

Comment: I am not familiar with SQL, should this be applied as a seperate filter or within the code behind the save record button?

Comment: I believe the OP is using MS Access, based on the (former) `acess` tag and other questions. If this is the case, solutions for SQL Server will not work.